# How can I supply pathconf with FUSE?

Tags: c, posix, fuse, pathconf

I would like to create a FUSE file system to mount tape archives. To do this correctly, I need to be able to supply replies to two `pathconf` keys, specifically `_PC_NAME_MAX` and `_PC_PATH_MAX`. It seems that FUSE takes the answer for the `_PC_NAME_MAX` key from the `statfs` function you provide, but I haven't found a way to set `_PC_PATH_MAX`. Is there a way to configure the answer to `_PC_PATH_MAX`? Is there in general a way to supply an answer to any `pathconf` call?

Comment: You know there is already a fuse implementation for tar right; archivemount?

Comment: @Michael I don't care about archivemount. Please stay on topic.

Comment: Um ... there are many more polite ways you could have said that, @FUZxxl.

Comment: @TomZych Sorry, I'm a bit grumpy right now because the FUSE API annoys me and because Michael started to go off topic. I don't care about archivemount because it doesn't solve the problem I want to solve and is quite inefficient at that. Also, archivemount doesn't bother at all to return proper values in `statfs` and employs cargo-cult techniques instead.

Comment: Well, granted it was off-topic; but for all Michael knew, you might not have heard of archivemount and it might have solved your problem in the wider context. Comments like that *can* be useful.

Comment: @TomZych Lastly, archivemount is horribly slow because it doesn't implement any sort of random access, as far as I'm concerned, every file access causes archivemount to re-read the entire archive from the beginning.

Comment: Asking `pathconf()` for `_PC_PATH_MAX` does not make sense on many systems such as Linux and FreeBSD since they define a global `PATH_MAX` constant that does not depend on the filesystem. Also, the effect of {PATH_MAX} is mostly on the system call level (how long pathnames are accepted) and does not prevent creating longer pathnames via chdir and/or rename. Why do you need to return a different value for this pathconf option?

Comment: @jilles The global constant `PATH_MAX` is only a coarse estimate. Portable programs should always call `pathconf`. A system may provide both a positive `PATH_MAX` and a differently-valued `_PC_PATH_MAX` key. I need this because the file system I'm trying to implement does not support paths longer than a certain limit and POSIX recommends to indicate that limit through `_PC_PATH_MAX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further research indicates that this is not possible with FUSE at all. What a sad excuse for an API.